# Finding the roots of a nonlinear equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, matlab, maple

Hello I am trying to find the real root of this equation
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{x}-\mathrm{y}-\frac{\mathrm{j}\,{\left(4\,{\left(\mathrm{t}+\frac{\mathrm{a}}{\mathrm{j}}\right)}^2+\frac{4\,\mathrm{v}}{\mathrm{j}}-\frac{2\,{\mathrm{a}}^2}{{\mathrm{j}}^2}\right)}^{\frac{3}{2}}}{8}+\left(\mathrm{v}+\mathrm{t}\,\mathrm{a}+\frac{\mathrm{j}\,\left({\left(\mathrm{t}+\frac{\mathrm{a}}{\mathrm{j}}\right)}^2+{\mathrm{t}}^2\right)}{2}\right)\,\left(2\,\mathrm{t}+\sqrt{2}\,\sqrt{2\,{\left(\mathrm{t}+\frac{\mathrm{a}}{\mathrm{j}}\right)}^2+\frac{2\,\mathrm{vi}}{\mathrm{j}}-\frac{{\mathrm{a}}^2}{{\mathrm{j}}^2}}+\frac{\mathrm{a}}{\mathrm{j}}\right)+\frac{\mathrm{j}\,\left({\left(\mathrm{t}+\frac{\mathrm{a}}{\mathrm{j}}\right)}^3-{\mathrm{t}}^3\right)}{3}-\frac{{\mathrm{t}}^2\,\left(\mathrm{a}-\mathrm{j}\,\left(\mathrm{t}+\frac{\mathrm{a}}{\mathrm{j}}\right)\right)}{2}- \mathrm{j}\,{\left(\mathrm{t}+\frac{\mathrm{a}}{\mathrm{j}}\right)}^2\,\left(\mathrm{t}+\frac{\mathrm{a}}{2\,\mathrm{j}}\right)-\frac{{\mathrm{t}}^2\,\mathrm{j}\,\left(\mathrm{t}+\frac{\mathrm{a}}{\mathrm{j}}\right)}{2} = 0
\end{equation}
to get the value of t where all my constants are real and a >0 , j >0, v >=0, x >0 and y >0
I tried to solve it with maple but I got a complex root. I tried also the fzero function but it is not helpful for since I will be using the result in a C++ program and I am working only with integers.
Would tell me please how can I solve this equation or how can I verify that this equation contains a real roots?
I am sorry for the lenght of the equation I hope it will be readable. I tried to do my best to make it more readable.

Comment: Could you please make the equation readable by collapsing and renaming the parameters ?

Comment: It would behoove you to rewrite this in a more readable way.

Comment: "I am working only with integers": is this a diophantine equation ??

Comment: Maple doesn't err. If it says complex root(s), then the root(s) is(are) complex.

Comment: No it is not a diophantine equation. I want to express t according to the others constants wich I know their values. For maple, the solution that I get after applying solve is roots of. I got 4 roots when I tested  each root after replacing the values of the other constants I get the complex number.

Comment: Do you know it should have real roots? Try making a plot of the LHS as you vary $t$, it might help.

Comment: Maybe try making $t+\frac{a}{j}=b$

Comment: @ Ariana Grande. Thank you for your help I have developed the equation mentionned below and I got a forth degree equation that I solved using Wolfram Mathematica. I got 2 real roots and 2 complex roots.